# How to not switch file when hitting a breakpoint?

Tags: visual-studio-code, breakpoints, vscode-debugger

I have `main.js` and import it to `main.debug.js`. In `main.debug.js` I have a breakpoint, either by clicking the breakpoint dot or by the `debugger` line. In `launch.json` I set:

```js
"program": "main.debug.js",
```

If I open `main.js` and hit F5, then when the debugger hit the breakpoint on `main.debug.js`, the editor will automatically switch to that file. Is there a way to set this off? In the setting i have tried to turn of Focus Editor On Break, Focus Window On Break, and set the Open Debug to neverOpen, but it still switches.

[image]
[image]

Comment: related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/23117 (from googling `github vscode issues debug do not focus breakpoint "feature-request"`)